# Dota 2 does not start _ creapswapchain()

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, graphics, steam, vulkan

Dota2 on Steam is not starting due to an error; after Vulkan update tonight, i am having the following error:

> Error
> CreateSwapChain():
> Unable to query the size of supported swapchain format.

I have **OS**: ubuntu 20.04, **CPU** : Intel® Core™ i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz × 8 , **GPU**: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] / Intel® HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)

My system info is as follows `steam`-`help`-`system information`:

```
Processor Information:
    CPU Vendor:  GenuineIntel
    CPU Brand:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
    CPU Family:  0x6
    CPU Model:  0x3c
    CPU Stepping:  0x3
    CPU Type:  0x0
    Speed:  3500 Mhz
    8 logical processors
    4 physical processors
    HyperThreading:  Supported
    FCMOV:  Supported
    SSE2:  Supported
    SSE3:  Supported
    SSSE3:  Supported
    SSE4a:  Unsupported
    SSE41:  Supported
    SSE42:  Supported
    AES:  Supported
    AVX:  Supported
    AVX2:  Unsupported
    AVX512F:  Unsupported
    AVX512PF:  Unsupported
    AVX512ER:  Unsupported
    AVX512CD:  Unsupported
    AVX512VNNI:  Unsupported
    SHA:  Unsupported
    CMPXCHG16B:  Supported
    LAHF/SAHF:  Supported
    PrefetchW:  Unsupported

Operating System Version:
    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (64 bit)
    Kernel Name:  Linux
    Kernel Version:  5.8.0-53-generic
    X Server Vendor:  The X.Org Foundation
    X Server Release:  12009000
    X Window Manager:  GNOME Shell
    Steam Runtime Version:  steam-runtime_0.20210422.0

Video Card:
    Driver:  Intel Open Source Technology Center Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
    Driver Version:  3.0 Mesa 20.2.6
    OpenGL Version: 3.0
    Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel
    Monitor Refresh Rate: 60 Hz
    VendorID:  0x8086
    DeviceID:  0x416
    Revision Not Detected
    Number of Monitors:  1
    Number of Logical Video Cards:  1
    Primary Display Resolution:  1920 x 1080
    Desktop Resolution: 1920 x 1080
    Primary Display Size: 13.39" x 7.48" (15.31" diag)
                                            34.0cm x 19.0cm (38.9cm diag)
    Primary VRAM Not Detected

Sound card:
    Audio device: Intel Haswell HDMI
```

The game was perfectly fine yesterday, however, it wouldn't start.

Comment: I solved this problem through removing all nvidia related files and then installing them again.

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same problem, I ended up removing everything that was related to my video card containing `Nvidia` and then installing them from the beginning. I tried many ways to do so and at last after purging every `Nvidia` app in my system I made it OK.